# Cordova build of Sencha App

Tags: android, ios, cordova, sencha-touch

I have a Sencha App which runs in a Cordova Wrapper. When I build the Sencha app in test mode everything works and the app runs on the device. But when I build the Sencha app in production I get the following popup on the startup of the app:

```
Requested: cordova.js seems to have been changed. Attempt to refresh the application?
```

The popup appears again and again. Does anyone know what's the reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

This message is because of Sencha Delta Update. The `production` parameter will create a stand-alone HTML5 web app which can update itself. Instead use `package` parameter to avoid delta updates:

```
$ sencha app build package
```

You can also edit `app.json` to disable delta update for individual files by removing the "update": "delta" parameter:

```
{   
    "path": "resources/js/cordova.js",
    "update": "delta" /* remove update parameter*/
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatly the app still tries to refresh the cordova.js even when I build it as a package. I found out that this comes from the Microloader file which is used for the production build. Is there a way to disable this behaviour?

Comment: @stefan I update the answer. Check if you have any file with `update` param in `app.json` file.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have enough reputation to comment that's why I am answering.

Have you updated your cmd? It can be the issue... If so you have to upgrade your app also using sencha cmd.